# Why is ess sup $f$ not ess max $f$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions

Consider a measure space $(X,\Sigma\,\mu)$. Given that one can easily prove that, $\mu$-a.e., $f \leq \text{ess} \sup_X f$, why is the notation not simply "$ \text{ess} \max_X f$"?

(Here $\text{ess} \sup_X f := \inf \{\xi \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}~|~f \leq \xi \text{ a.e.} \}$).

Comment: I think the major reason one would not want to call it a maximum is if that essential supremum is infinite. It is standard to consider maximums/minimums to be attained in the real numbers and to consider the $\pm \infty$ as a separate case. The choice of word "supremum" already does that for us.

Comment: Oh. I just realised why I was getting confused about it. What I was thinking of was why we can't define it as
\begin{equation} \text{ess} \sup_X f := \min \{\xi \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}~|~ f\leq \xi \text{ a.e.} \}. \end{equation}
I think in this case it would be okay. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I told you otherwise it was because you were confused :P aren't we all, sometimes...

Comment: Too many times...

Answer (score 3):

Usually "max" refers to a supremum that is attained, i.e., that is actually a value of the function.  Since the essential supremum need not be attained (let alone attained "essentially", which I suppose would mean attained on a set of positive measure), it's clearer to say "essential supremum".

Comment: Thanks, I realised the mistake in my question. See my answer to Patrick Da Silva, above.